# Converting JSON string to an array in ColdFusion MX7

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I have a cookie value like:

```
"[{"index":"1","name":"TimePeriod","hidden":false},{"index":"2","name":"Enquiries","hidden":false},{"index":"3","name":"Online","hidden":false}]"
```

I would like to use this cookie value as an array in ColdFusion. What would be the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

The normal answer would be use the built-in [**deserializeJson**](http://cfdocs.org/) function, but since that function wasn't available in CFMX7 (it arrived in CF8), you will need to use a UDF to achieve the same thing.

There are two sites which contain resources of this type, [**cflib.org**](http://cflib.org) and [**riaforge.org**](http://riaforge.org), each of which have a different potential solution for MX7.

Searching [CFlib](http://cflib.org) provides [**JsonDecode**](http://cflib.org/udf/jsondecode). (CFLib has a specific filter for "Maximum Required CF Version", so you can ensure any results that appear will work for your version.)

Searching [riaforge](http://riaforge.org) provides [**JSONUtil**](http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/), which runs on MX7 (but also claims better type mapping than the newer built-in functions).

Since MX7 runs on Java, you can likely also make use of any of the numerous Java libraries listed on [json.org](http://json.org), using [createObject/java](http://cfdocs.org/createobject-java-or-ejb-object).

Answer (score 7):

JSON serialization was added natively in CF8.

If you are on MX7 look on [riaforge.org](http://www.riaforge.org) for a library that will deSerialize JSON for you.

Comment: Welcome. (Links for the lazy like me ;-)